# Как узнать дерикторию текущего процесса, если он был запущен другим процессом

Tags: c#, процесс

Вроде бы простейшая команда:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Но она выдает директорию процесса который запустил текущий процесс в котором я исполняю эту команду. Почему ссохраняется такая странная связь и как узнать всетаки где находится запущенный просесс из самого процесса?

Запускаю:

```
Process.Start(path + "\\Updater.exe");
```

Comment: Что значит "где находится запущенный просесс"? Ехе-файл?

Comment: верно путь на диске

Answer (score 1):

Рабочая директория, которую возвращает `Environment.CurrentDirectory`, задается при запуске процесса, в общем случае, операционной системой. Т.к. запуск нового процесса вы делаете самостоятельно из контекста своей программы, то и ответственность за назначение рабочей директории лежит на вас и вашей программе. Тоже касается привилегий доступа процесса - на дочерние процессы распространяются привилегии родительского процесса.

Узнать где лежит файл из которого был запущен дочерний процесс можно так:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)
string path = fi.DirectoryName;
```

Другой вариант - перед запуском процесса задать рабочую директорию руками:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = path;
Process.Start(path + "\\Updater.exe");
```

Оба трюка вызывают панику у антивируса. Хотя возможно у меня параноидальные настройки стоят.

Comment: Да нет, многие аверы орут как резанные на многие действия с I/O.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно что-то из этого, похоже:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
```

Answer (score 0):

GetModuleFileName() запишет в буффер путь к EXE-файлу, из которого функция дернута, если параметр hModule установлен в ноль.